# Помогите 'начать' освоение Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, javascript, facebook-api

Добрый вечер, что-то никак не могу понять с чего начать осваивать Facebook API. Многие документации ссылаются на библиотеку facebook api, которой уже даже нету в документации фейсбука. В документации же даются какие-то библиотеки, вот [например для php и javascript](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/), но черт возьми там ссылка на ссылку дается, не могу понять что и куда подключать. Кто-то может подтолкнуть? Вообще, всё что мне нужно от facebook api это регистрация пользователя на моём сайте и при регистрации вытащить его стандартные данные с фейсбука + его фотки из фотоальбома. Куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [**тут**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) авторизация.